# How to get JSON object's property?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am working on a PHP application developed using Zend 2.2.4 with SQL Server database. 
Currently I am working on saving and retrieving JSON data from the database. I use the following line to encode the array in JSON format and then save it to the database:

```
$reportData = json_encode($reportData);
```

I can retrieve the data from the database but not sure if it's being formatted in  JSON format. I displayed the contents of the JSON values in JavScript using 'console.log' and the output seems fine:

```
reportData: "{"chartData":[{"name":"test","data":[1,2,3]}],"pieData":[{"name":"test-2","type":"pie","data":[[2,4,1],]}]}"
```

But if I try `console.log(reportData.chartData)`, I get an 'undefined' message in the console.

Can someone kindly advise on what I'm doing wrong please? Appreciate any help.

Comment: That's a JSON string, you should parse it.

Comment: You want to retrieve json properties in PHP or JS ?